# Is there any way to host both react and vanilla javascipt webpages together?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, heroku, hosting

I need to host an entire web application. It is mainly built with ReactJS, but I have some parts of the page running vanilla javascript. Is there any way to host the web app which is using both React and vanilla javascript? (I'm using nodeJS in the backend and mongoDB is the database)

Comment: What is the problem you are getting on having both on the same page? Please share errors and what you tried. There's no issue OOTB

Comment: I haven't tried it yet, I was having a doubt whether it would work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no problem with combining React and vanilla js.
You can put the React app in an iframe or put the `root` element your react app is rendered in somewhere in the body.